# Unable to connect to the arduino port with visual studi (Access to the port 'COM4' is deneid)

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I am making a simple Visual Studio C# interface, in which the user will write a text, and then the text will be sent to the Arduino through an LCD 1602 module (with a header).

The Arduino code seems to be working correctly, but when addressing to the Visual Studio text, it says the access to the port is denied.

I think the main issue is with C# Code, but it could be as well the Arduino code, just in case I will post both codes and the methods of the Visual Studio which I think have the problem.

C# Code:

```cs
private void ConnectB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!isConnected)
    {
        connectToArudino();
    }
    else
    {
        disconnectFromArduino();
    }
}

private void connectToArudino()
{
    try
    {
        isConnected = true;
        MessageBox.Show("The value is: " + isConnected.ToString());
        string selectedPort = COMComboBox.GetItemText(COMComboBox.SelectedItem);
        port = new SerialPort(selectedPort, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        port.Open();
        port.Write("#STAR\n");
        ConnectB.Text = "Disconnected";
        Safe.Enabled = true;
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error has Ocurred: " + err.Message);
    }

}

private void disconnectFromArduino()
{
    try
    {
        isConnected = false;
        port.Write("#STOP\n");
        port.Close();
        ConnectB.Text = "Connected";
        Safe.Enabled = false;
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Another Error: " + err.Message);
    }
}
```

Arduino Code:

```c
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

String inputString = "";         // a string to hold incoming data
boolean stringComplete = false;  // whether the string is complete
String commandString = "";

boolean isConnected = false;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    lcd.begin();
    lcd.backlight();
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Ready to Connect");
}

void loop() {
    if (stringComplete)
    {
        stringComplete = false;
        getCommand();

        if (commandString.equals("STAR"))
        {
            lcd.clear();
        }
        if (commandString.equals("STOP"))
        {
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.print("Connected");
        }
        else if (commandString.equals("TEXT"))
        {
            String text = getTextToPrint();
            printText(text);
        }

        inputString = "";
    }
}

void getCommand()
{
    if (inputString.length() > 0)
    {
        commandString = inputString.substring(1, 5);
    }
}

String getTextToPrint()
{
    String value = inputString.substring(5, inputString.length() - 2);
    return value;
}

void printText(String text)
{
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    if (text.length() < 16)
    {
        lcd.print(text);
    }
    else
    {
        lcd.print(text.substring(0, 16));
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(text.substring(16, 32));
    }
}

void serialEvent() {
    while (Serial.available()) {
        char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
        inputString += inChar;
        if (inChar == '\n') {
            stringComplete = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting that the visual code will connect correctly to the arduino, and the text written in the program is correctly displayed in the LCD module.

Comment: What is the exact full error message you get ... it seems you open port for first time and then did not close it properly

Comment: The following may be of interest: [SerialPort.NewLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.newline?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) and [SerialPort.WriteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.writeline?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0).  You may consider reading all of the documentation for the [SerialPort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) class.